# Is it possible to code Volumetric MA on pine?

Tags: pine-script

I've noticed that while using TV's inbuilt Volume indicator, it has an inbuilt MA, and I'd like to use that for an indicator that I'm making.

Or is it possible to use that Volumetric MA as an inbuilt indicator?

Here's some code that I've tried(which is quite wrong)

```
a = volume[0]
b = close[0]/20
vsma = volume[b]
plot(a, title='Volume', color=color.new(color.blue, 0), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_histogram)
plot(vsma, title='Volume', color=color.new(color.yellow, 70), linewidth=2, style=plot.style_line)
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just `ma` over `volume` built-in variable.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

len = input.int(20, "Length", minval=1)
vol_ma = ta.sma(volume, len)
plot(vol_ma)
```